# CNN with keras, accuracy remains constant and does not improve

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train my model by [finetuning](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface#finetuning) a pretrained [model](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface)(vggface). My model has 12 classes with 1774 training images and 313 validation images, each class having around 150 images.
So far I have been able to achieve a max accuracy around 80% with the following script in keras:

```
img_width, img_height = 224, 224

vggface = VGGFace(model='resnet50', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

last_layer = vggface.get_layer('avg_pool').output
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
out = Dense(12, activation='softmax', name='classifier')(x)
custom_vgg_model = Model(vggface.input, out)


# Create the model
model = models.Sequential()

# Add the convolutional base model
model.add(custom_vgg_model)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=20,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Change the batchsize according to your system RAM
train_batchsize = 16
val_batchsize = 16

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_path,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=train_batchsize,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_path,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=val_batchsize,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True)

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3),
              metrics=['acc'])
# Train the model
history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples/train_generator.batch_size ,
      epochs=50,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=validation_generator.samples/validation_generator.batch_size,
      verbose=1)
```

So far I have tried:

- By increasing the epochs upto 100.
- By changing the learning rate.
- By changing the optimizer to rmsprop. But that gave even worse results.
- I was suggested to add more FC layers with dropout and batch normalization. I 
  did that, still the validation accuracy was around 79%.

Here's my change for that:

```
vggface = VGGFace(model='resnet50', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

#vgg_model = VGGFace(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

last_layer = vggface.get_layer('avg_pool').output
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
xx = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(x)
x1 = BatchNormalization()(xx)
x2 = Dropout(0.3)(xx)

y = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(x2)
yy = BatchNormalization()(y)
y1 = Dropout(0.3)(y)

z = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(y1)
zz = BatchNormalization()(z)
z1 = Dropout(0.6)(zz)

x3 = Dense(12, activation='softmax', name='classifier')(z1)

custom_vgg_model = Model(vggface.input, x3)
```

I have made my activation as softmax now as suggested by [SymbolixAU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5977215/symbolixau) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079585/cnn-with-keras-accuracy-not-improving?rq=1). The val acc is now 81% still, while the training acc gets close to 99%

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For anyone who may see this, start with a higher learning rate or use a learning rate scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your connections. In the first two blocks the BatchNormalization is not connected to the dropout. Change the input of the two first dropout.

```
xx = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(x)
x1 = BatchNormalization()(xx)
x2 = Dropout(0.3)(x1)

y = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(x2)
yy = BatchNormalization()(y)
y1 = Dropout(0.3)(yy)
```

The values you give implies that your network is overfitting. The batch normalization or adding more dropout might help. But, given the small number of images you should really try image augmentation to increase the number of training images.

Comment: Oh sorry. That was my mistake. I have corrected that already.

Comment: Should I use dropout with values like 0.8 or something? OR should I gradually increase and see which works better

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that the Dense layers should have a dropout of 0.3 to 0.4 and Conv2D layers should have a dropout of 0.2. But, this could vary depending on the likelihood  of overfitting for you dataset and you will have to experiment and see which one works for you.

Comment: You should really do image augmentation: change scale, rotation, shear.. so the network can train on more examples. This will probably give you the best improvement. Check in the keras website